# Load a QGroupbox from ui file multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm working on an app and I'd like to keep the GUI separated from the code as much as I can.

Id like to load a ui file that contains only a QGroupBox into my main Ui.
Is that possible to do?

main Ui is a QMainWindow/Qwidget/QTabWidget design, nothing really special.
I'd like the groupbox show on one of the tab (let's say, "FirstTab")

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv) #Main Window

Main = uic.loadUi("main.ui")
MyGroupBox = uic.loadUi("groupbox.ui")

def Add_groupbox():
    # here the magic happens :)

Main.button.pressed.connect(Add_groupbox)

Main.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your description is confusing. 1) Does the "FirstTab" tab already exist or should it be created? 2) Do you want me to load a new QGroupBox every time the button is pressed ?, that is if it is pressed n times then n tabs must be created

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your reply
FirstTab already exists and I want to add the QGroupBox to the existing tab multiple times but I can handle that part :)

Comment: Let's say the button is pressed then the QGroupBox was added to "FirstTab", how should a second QGroupBox be added to the same tab? Do you want to place it vertically or horizontally or have the new QGroupBox replace the previous QGroupBox?

Comment: The new QGroupBox goes under the previous one. I will have maximum 3 of them in a vertical layout. No, they won't replace each other, all of them will be visible.

Comment: And if the button is pressed 10 times as it should be shown? Also share the .ui

Comment: No, only 3 times, but I can handle that part. Unfortunately, I cant share the uis because they contain sensitive information.
The main.ui is a basic MainWindow with a Tab and the qroupbox just as its name says, a groupbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208410/discussion-between-jtamasi-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Then create new .ui that maintain the structure and that does not have sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
Just needed a layout.

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv) #Main Window

Main = uic.loadUi("main.ui")
MyGroupBox = uic.loadUi("groupbox.ui")

def Add_groupbox():
    # Just needed a layout
    Vlayout.addWidget(MyGroupBox)

Main.button.pressed.connect(Add_groupbox)

Main.show()
app.exec_()
```